# android, enable xml validation in xml pull parser

Tags: android, xmlpullparser, simple-framework

I'm using [simplexml](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) framework on Android and it parse xml internally with xmlpullparser. There is any capabilities to enable xml validation to prevent XXE attacks or any settings for this?

Thanks!

Comment: @Terel `simplexml` internally uses `xmlpullparser` on Android (see it in `org.simpleframework.xml.stream.ProviderFactory#getInstance`) for parsing. But pullparser doesn't support external entity resolutions at all, so xxe attacks can't be applied in this case. Please correct me if i'm wrong.